# The correct word

Tags: word-usage

What’s the difference between the words “ relative” and “relation”? I think they are synonyms and mean a person of the same family. But are there any differences in their usage?

Comment: What did your dictionaries, thesauruses or search engines leave unclear?

Answer (score 1):

Relative and relation are synonyms when they are nouns referring to family relations.  [Relative](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/relative) has meanings that [relation](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/relation) doesn't have and vice-versa.

Relative is also an antonym of absolute as in this [definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/relative):

> something dependent upon external conditions for its specific nature,
>   size, etc.

[Relation](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/relation) can also refer to non-familial relations, like relations between countries, friends, work, etc.  It also be used as a polite way of describing 
sexual intercourse

[Relative](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/relation) can also serve as an adjective within a sentence while the word relation never can.

Comment: This is a question for English Language Learners, not this site. And "relation" by itself does not mean "sexual intercourse", which is itself a euphemism for the venerable English word, "fucking".

Answer (score 0):

In the US, ***relatives*** is more commonly used to describe extended family than ***relations*** - although it is more common in the South to hear the latter term.

Among those who would use both terms, ***"relatives"*** is more likely to describe folks that you might see at a holiday gathering, while  ***"relations"*** are often met for the first time at the funeral of a family patriarch.